# Rails Paperclip File Type Validation - Add DWG?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, paperclip

Using Rails 5 and the latest Paperclip release, i'm struggling to be able to upload files with .dwg extensions. Anyone know how this might be achieved?

In the model that takes the attachment I have the following. I want to accept .dwg file extensions. I have found https://www.sitepoint.com/mime-types-complete-list and tried "application/dwg" but it won't validate. Not sure if the issue relates to my development environment not recognising the MIME types.

```
validates_attachment_content_type :file, :content_type => [
"application/pdf",
"application/msword",
"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
"application/msexcel",
"application/vnd.ms-excel",
"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
"text/plain",
"image/jpg",
"image/jpeg",
"image/png",
"image/gif"]
```

Comment: can you add sample code of what you did?

Comment: Updated the original post, thanks